# Control the opacity of "covered" elements in Beamer

Tags: beamer, transparency

In [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), I'm using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to show "covered" elements transparently before they appear in full. However, I find the transparent text too opaque.

How can I adjust the opacity / transparency / alpha of the covered elements?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% desired command to control the level of opacity
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \pause
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\setbeamercovered{transparent=⟨percentage⟩}`, where `⟨percentage⟩` is between `0` and `100`. Quoting the manual, `You can specify a different ⟨percentage⟩, where 0 means “totally transparent” and 100 means “totally opaque".`

Comment: I've used `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` before and can't recommend it. It's distracting for the audience and it doesn't play well if you have images that also use transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beamer manual says on p. 194

[image]

Here is an illustration.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% desired command to control the level of opacity
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,100}
{\setbeamercovered{transparent=\X}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\texttt{\textbackslash setbeamercovered\{transparent=\X\}}}
\pause
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}}
\end{document}
```

[image]